# Tags not working after game is built

Tags: unity-game-engine

For anyone wondering they are assigned under the Tags dropdown in the Tags & Layers options, they work just fine in the editor, but returning tag not defined after game is built.

Tried both `Find.GameObjectWithTag` & `Find.WithTag`

Also tried a google search but only one thread was actually related to my issue and still didn't fixed it, it's so frustrating.

EDIT:

Also I have some weird thing going on with the tags where upon deletion of one, it's not actually deleted it remains by the name of "(removed)" but it's still there and it takes up space.

Comment: Please post some code snippets

Answer (score 0):

The Tag collection is built from objects loaded at run-time.

Tag labels are also stored in Project Settings, not Assets folder.  Only the tag **index** is stored on the serialised objects (in Assets).

I don't really understand what your initial problem is.  Try posting some code or screenshots.